# web3js how to simulate a transaction without getting it mined

Tags: web3js

How do I simulate a transaction using web3js? I want to know whether the token is a scam honeypot and find out how much buy and sell tax it has.

Answer (score 0):

on the some project, you can simulate transactions before doing that(for example swap tokens in uniswap) but in my opinion, the best solution for interacting with real blockchain is forks,you can for blockchain with RPC providers and simulate your transactions.
I suggest to read [this](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/ethereum-development/smart-contracts/how-to-fork-ethereum-blockchain-with-ganache/).

Comment: This is cool but I need data that's based on live blockchain status. Doing this based on a forked blockchain will return data that's valid up to the latest block that's forked. The problem after this is what if the guy has changed the tax just the block after you did the fork? If it could be a way to sync the forked blockchain with the original one, it would easily solve this problem.

Comment: I undrestand what you say.you can trigger to generate a fork for each block and test your transaction .other solution is, to watch the event of your target address and generate a fork after any effective events and then test you transaction.